# Create dynamic column and save output in ES

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

Here is my question. I have following columns which has Int type.

1) DurationA

2) DurationB

3) Duration C = DurationB-DurationA

DurationA and DurationB values comes from Different CSV file which I am loading to ES through Logstash

Question

1) is there anyway I can create column DurationC and save value in ES while I am processing CSV file ?

2) if not possible what function I should use in ES Query to get the desired result (DurationB-DurationA)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ruby` filter as:

```
filter {
  ruby {
    code => "event['Duration C'] = event['Duration B'].to_f - event['Duration A'].to_f"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `ruby` filter is an option, but there is a non-core plugin that was built for mathematical calculations: https://github.com/robin13/logstash-filter-math

And a bit of guide you can find here: http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/logstash-filter-math/LogStash/Filters/Math

Comment: Thanks Alpert and Anderi for your answer. As DurationA and DurationB comes from different CSV file , I really doubt I can apply any formula while loading data into ES using Logstash. DurationA and DurationB values is there in Same document so might I need to update my ES document once data load is complete. I am just looking how can I update it using aggregate function ? Let me know if you have any suggestion for that..